# If-else Function Does Not Run

Tags: html, function, if-statement, menu, onclick

When the menu button div is clicked, I want it to transitionm which it does, and make the menu div appear, the code for which is in a different function. For some reason, the second function does not run. If I remove the else{} section it seems to work, however. How do I fix this?

```
            #menubtn {
                margin-top:4px;
                margin-left:-300px;
                position:absolute;
                display:inline-block;
            }
            #menubtn div {
                width:35px;
                height:5px;
                background-color:black;
                margin:6px 0;
                transition: 0.4s;
            }
            .change #bar1 {
                transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
            }
            .change #bar2 {
                opacity:0;
            }
            .change #bar3 {
                transform:rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
            }
            #menu {
                background-color:white;
                width:300px;
                height:400px;
                position:absolute;
                top:80px;
                border-right:solid 5px rgba(35, 203, 167, 1);
                border-bottom:solid 5px rgba(35, 203, 167, 1);
                z-index:10;
                transition: width 1s;
                overflow:hidden;
                display:none;
            }
```

```
<div id="menubtn" onclick="menu(this); menushow()">
            <div id="bar1"></div>
            <div id="bar2"></div>
            <div id="bar3"></div>
        </div>
<div id="menu">
            <h1>Menu</h1>
            <a href="">Home</a><br>
            <a href="">About me!</a><br>
            <a href="">Bread</a><br>
            <a href="">Sweet treats</a><br>
            <a href="">How to start baking</a>
        </div>
```

```
    function menu(x) {
        x.classList.toggle("change")
    }
    var menushow = "false"
    function menushow() {
        if (menushow == "false") {
        document.getElementById("menu").style.display="block";
        menushow = "true";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("menu").style.display="none";
            menushow = "false";
        }
    }
```

Comment: `menushow = "false"` vs `function menushow()` do you see anything strange?

Comment: You can also make use of the `toggle` method, check it out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)

Comment: @Berto99 ...? The spelling of both is the same. Removing the "" doesn't make a difference I don't think. Would this method not work?

Comment: @FranciscaRiosDurkin: *"The spelling of both is the same"* - Indeed, which is a problem.  You're trying to have two references with the same name, so the code has no way to distinguish between then.  Rename one of them.

Comment: @Richardo Sanchez Would the js look like this:     function menushow() {
        var menu = document.getElementById("menu")
        menu.classList.toggle("menu")
    }

Answer (score 0):

The variable has the same name as the function, so the code has no way to distinguish between the two. If you change the name of the variable or the function (here I changed the variable name) the code will run as it should.

```
    var mshow = "false"
    function menushow() {
        if (mshow == "false") {
        document.getElementById("menu").style.display="block";
        mshow = "true";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("menu").style.display="none";
            mshow = "false";
        }
    }
```